# Deleting everything except last part of a String?

Tags: java, string, url

What kind of method would I use to make this:

`http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip`

To

`file1.zip`?

Comment: What is the end use of this?  E.G. why does the app require `file1.zip` as opposed to `files/file1.zip` (the 'file' or 'path') part of the URL?

Answer (score 7):

```
String yourString = "http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip";  
int index = yourString.lastIndexOf('/');    
String targetString = yourString.substring(index + 1);  
System.out.println(targetString);// file1.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip";
        str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to extract the last part:

```
@Test
public void extractFileNameFromUrl() {
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\w+.]*$").matcher("http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip");
    Assert.assertEquals("file1.zip", matcher.find() ? matcher.group(0) : null);
}
```

It'll return only "file1.zip". Included here as a test as I used it to validate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use split:

```
String[] arr = "http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip".split("/");
```

Then:

```
String lastPart = arr[arr.length-1];
```

**Update:** Another simpler way to get this:

```
File file = new File("http://www.site.net/files/file1.zip");
System.out.printf("Path: [%s]%n", file.getName()); // file1.zip
```

Comment: This will work but `split` uses a regex for this.IMHO it is too much overhead to just get the last part of the string.

Comment: @Cratylus: Yes it uses regex but I'm not sure about `too much overhead` part.

Comment: Well for really short strings using a regex (which builds a tree etc) seems to much over a simple loop. But this is my opinion